# {{variable}} not working in product description

Tags: magento-1.9, media-images

```
<img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/my_image_large.png"}}" height="100" width="300" />
```

The previous code is included in products description. In frontend the result looks like this:

```
<img alt="" src="{WWWWW{WWWWWmedia url=" wysiwyg="" my_image_large.png"wwwww}wwwww}"="" height="100" width="300">
```

Does anybody know what could cause something like that?

---

-----------UPDATE-------------

I found that all variables work this way. They all give the same code:

`{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}`

gives

`{WWWWW{WWWWWconfig path="web/secure/base_url"WWWWW}WWWWW}`

---

-----------UPDATE 2-------------

I found that this solution works, when displaying product description:

```
$_description = $this->getProduct()->getDescription();
$_myHelper = Mage::helper('cms');
$_processor = $_myHelper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
echo $_processor->filter($_description);
```

It doesn't make sense and it's a temporary solution. But it might give you a clue of what's causing the issue here.

Comment: Are you getting anything in Magento's log files?

Answer (score 0):

You escape the media url function by using double quotes withing the brackets. try:

```
src="{{media url=wysiwyg/my_image_large.png}}"
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting the same result

Comment: You tried without the double quotes in the double brackets? If that doesn't work, maybe use single quotes withing the brackets?

Comment: please read my question update. Problem seems to be in {{ and not in brackets

Answer (score 0):

try this

replace `media url="wysiwyg/my_image_large.png"` with  `media url='wysiwyg/my_image_large.png'`  or `media url="wysiwyg/my_image_large.png"` with  `media url=wysiwyg/my_image_large.png` inside img tag

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, use it like this: `<img src="{{media url=&quot;wysiwyg/my_image_large.png&quot;}}" alt=""  style="height="100" width="300"" />`

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting the same result